# Optimise MySQL query having joins

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, query-optimization

How do I optimise my query below. As it have too many joins

```
    SELECT `providers`.`provider_id`, `providers`.`providerFirstName`, `providers`.`providerLastName`, `providers`.`email`, `providers`.`phoneNumber`, `providers`.`address`, `providers`.`agencyName`, `providers`.`practiceCounty`, `providers`.`city`, `providers`.`state`, `providers`.`zip`, `providers`.`mondayHours`, `providers`.`tuesdayHours`, `providers`.`wednesdayHours`, `providers`.`thursdayHours`, `providers`.`fridayHours`, `providers`.`saturdayHours`, `providers`.`sundayHours`, `providers`.`additionalInfo`, `providers`.`website`, `providers`.`newClientsAcceptance`, `providers`.`updatedBy`, `providers`.`otherCategories`, `providers`.`otherInsurances`, `providers`.`otherTelehealthServices`, `providers`.`createdAt`, `providers`.`updatedAt`, `ProviderInsurances`.`provider_insurance_id` AS `ProviderInsurances.provider_insurance_id`, `ProviderInsurances`.`insurance_id` AS `ProviderInsurances.insurance_id`, `ProviderInsurances->Insurance`.`insurance_id` AS `ProviderInsurances.Insurance.insurance_id`, `ProviderInsurances->Insurance`.`insurance_name` AS `ProviderInsurances.Insurance.insurance_name`, `ProviderClients`.`provider_client_id` AS `ProviderClients.provider_client_id`, `ProviderClients`.`client_id` AS `ProviderClients.client_id`, `ProviderClients->Client`.`client_id` AS `ProviderClients.Client.client_id`, `ProviderClients->Client`.`client_name` AS `ProviderClients.Client.client_name`, `ProviderCounties`.`provider_county_id` AS `ProviderCounties.provider_county_id`, `ProviderCounties`.`county_id` AS `ProviderCounties.county_id`, `ProviderCounties->County`.`county_id` AS `ProviderCounties.County.county_id`, `ProviderCounties->County`.`county_name` AS `ProviderCounties.County.county_name`, `ProviderSpecialities`.`provider_speciality_id` AS `ProviderSpecialities.provider_speciality_id`, `ProviderSpecialities`.`speciality_id` AS `ProviderSpecialities.speciality_id`, `ProviderSpecialities->Speciality`.`speciality_id` AS `ProviderSpecialities.Speciality.speciality_id`, `ProviderSpecialities->Speciality`.`speciality_name` AS `ProviderSpecialities.Speciality.speciality_name`, `ProviderCategories`.`provider_category_id` AS `ProviderCategories.provider_category_id`, `ProviderCategories`.`category_id` AS `ProviderCategories.category_id`, `ProviderCategories->Category`.`category_id` AS `ProviderCategories.Category.category_id`, `ProviderCategories->Category`.`category_name` AS `ProviderCategories.Category.category_name`, `Telehealths`.`telehealth_id` AS `Telehealths.telehealth_id`, `Telehealths`.`telehealth_name` AS `Telehealths.telehealth_name` 
FROM `providers` AS `providers` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `provider_insurances` AS `ProviderInsurances` ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `ProviderInsurances`.`provider_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `insurance` AS `ProviderInsurances->Insurance` ON `ProviderInsurances`.`insurance_id` = `ProviderInsurances->Insurance`.`insurance_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `provider_clients` AS `ProviderClients` ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `ProviderClients`.`provider_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `clients` AS `ProviderClients->Client` ON `ProviderClients`.`client_id` = `ProviderClients->Client`.`client_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `provider_counties` AS `ProviderCounties` ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `ProviderCounties`.`provider_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `counties` AS `ProviderCounties->County` ON `ProviderCounties`.`county_id` = `ProviderCounties->County`.`county_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `provider_specialities` AS `ProviderSpecialities` ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `ProviderSpecialities`.`provider_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `specialities` AS `ProviderSpecialities->Speciality` ON `ProviderSpecialities`.`speciality_id` = `ProviderSpecialities->Speciality`.`speciality_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `provider_categories` AS `ProviderCategories` ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `ProviderCategories`.`provider_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` AS `ProviderCategories->Category` ON `ProviderCategories`.`category_id` = `ProviderCategories->Category`.`category_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `telehealth` AS `Telehealths` ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `Telehealths`.`provider_id` 
WHERE `providers`.`updatedAt` 
BETWEEN '2019-08-06 18:30:00' AND '2019-08-08 00:00:00';
```

What could be the best practice to reduce execution time. Please help.

I have added "EXPLAIN SELECT" Output below
[image]

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames I have added the screenshot above

Comment: Please don't sort the rows of `EXPLAIN`; the order of the rows is critical information.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE provider_counties`

Answer (score 1):

be sure you have proper index on columns involved  in join  eg:

for

```
table  provider_insurances columns  (provider_id, insurance_id)
table  insurance columns (insurance_id)
table  provider_clients columns (provider_id)
...
....
table  providers columns (updatedAt, provider_id )
```

Comment: Yes I have added normal index for updatedAt and primary key index for all the remaining columns above. But still the execution time is same

Comment: there also aother column involved  not only primary key .. so check fi you have the indexes  as suggested ..

Comment: @rjirji   To clarify the  answer already posted by scaisEdge, you have 11 outer joins which specify  columns to be joined (ON `providers`.`provider_id` = `ProviderInsurances`.`provider_id`).  You have to make sure each of these 22 columns are indexed.  Also, all columns in the Where clause should be indexed for better performance.

Comment: @James Is primary key an index? All the 22 columns are given primary key and the column in where clause is given a custom index. Is that enough?

Comment: @rjirji - Yes a `PRIMARY KEY` in an index.  (And it is a `UNIQUE` index.)

Comment: @rjirji PRIMARY KEY is  an index but is not waht you need  for your  where clause and some of your join clause  ..  .. ithink you should take a deep look at what is an index ...and don't stop at a title

Comment: @rjirji Yes, a primary key is an index so if the columns specified in the joins are all primary keys or if the columns are indexed then it's correct and the db will be able to search those columns much much quicker than if they were not indexed!

Answer (score -1):

you can use sequelize ORM to handle your query joins. link => [https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html]

Comment: It is not about sequelize. I am asking ow to optimise the execution time

Comment: This is not an answer.